# How to get the correct format of date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Table1

```
Date1 (datatype is integer)

25969 
25969
....
```

I want to get a correct format of the date like (18-05-2012)

The above date1 column values output is

```
Date1

17-05-2012
17-05-2012
...
```

How to make a query for this.

Need query help

Comment: How should the integer values be interpreted as dates?

Comment: How is your date being stored?  You obviously have a count of something, but what is it?  In addition, how did you get the first resultset that you posted?

Comment: If we've got to deduce the mapping between integers and dates ourselves, we'll need more than 1 example - preferably at least 5 pairs of (int,date).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming your `int` is UNIXTIME (seconds since 1970/01/01)

Something like:

```
declare @UNIX_TIME int
select @UNIX_TIME = 1111111111
-- Using dateadd to add seconds to 1970-01-01
select [Datetime from UNIX Time] = dateadd(ss,@UNIX_TIME,'1970-01-01')
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
select convert(varchar(50), cast(Date1 as datetime), 105) 
from table
```